# Identifying REST Operation from its URL patterns?

Tags: rest

I was just wondering if we can find out the REST Operation from its URL? Like like identification that can be used to determine whether it is GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me highlight that REST is architectural style and it is *protocol-independent*. But I haven't come across any applications doing REST over a protocol that is not HTTP(S). So, when you say *REST operation*, I understand it as *HTTP request*.

---

**URL** stands from **U**niversal **R**eource **L**ocator and it is meant for, well, **locating resources** in the server. Just that. URLs locate resources and are not meant to express any operation (unless you are doing RPC, but I guess that's not what you want).

On the other hand, the **request method** is the primary source of request semantics, as it indicates the purpose for which the client has made this request and what is expected by the client as a successful result.

---

Having said that, let me go back to your questions:

> I was just wondering if we can find out the REST Operation from its URL?

No. The URL will (or at least should) tell you about the resource which is the target of the operation expressed by the HTTP method.

> Like identification that can be used to determine whether it is `GET`/`POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE` etc?

If I understand your question correctly, as I answered above, no.

But, if you want to identify the request methods supported by a given resource, then you can use the [`OPTIONS`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) method. Consider the following request as example:

```
OPTIONS /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

The server will respond with something similar to:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
```

Where the [`Allow`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1) header contains a list of the methods supported by the target resource.